# Factors causing entelechia not to realize

Tags: aristotle, ancient-philosophy

Is there a term in Aristotle's work for the factors that cause entelechia not to realize? Does he address these somewhere? I mean, bodies work in certain energeia and can be interrupted from developing fully towards entelechia.

Comment: I'd suggest that the *typical* acorn grows into the *typical* mature  oak; which doesn't mean that this actually existing acorn will necessarily grow into an oak - I might chop it down next year; it would be interesting to see what Aristotle has to say.

Comment: @MoziburUllah true, though I had in mind more subtle cases. Like in your example, insufficient amount of light or water or, better, too acidic soil. So that you could say that something is keeping the acorn back from developing towards its aim. I. e. speaking in terms of conditions and constraining factors.